# KendoUI Grid number column will not edit as number

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a column called "Quantity", which is connected to the field (column name) "quantity".

In my model I have it set like so:

```
...
quantity: {
    type: 'number',
    editable: true,
    validation: {
        min: 1
    }
}
...
```

However, when I click on the cell to edit it, it does nothing.

If I change the `type:` to string, it works fine. Obviously I would like this to be number so I can use the number rollers.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The information you shared does not show where the issue comes from, probably you are missing something.

Check this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/opecuk/1/edit) - it is all the same and it works as expected, try to edit the Id field which is of type **number**.

```
    schema: {
    model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
            Id: { type: "number" },
            Name: { type: "string" },
            Position: { type: "number" }
        }
    }
}
```